# Agrupar por 2 columnas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT pv.nombre, tf.total
FROM ventas v
JOIN puntoVenta pv ON v.idPuntoVenta = pv.id
JOIN totalFactura tf ON v.codeFac = tf.codeFac
WHERE v.idEvento = '2' AND v.status = 'approved'
GROUP BY v.codeFac
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

| nombre | total |
| --- | --- |
| Diamante | 160000 |
| Diamante | 170000 |
| Diamante | 140000 |
| Diamante | 610000 |
| Diamante | 320000 |
| Parqueadero | 320000 |
| Parqueadero | 290000 |

Necesito obtener el total de la venta por cada **Punto de Venta** [ Diamante o Parqueadero ]. He intentando con:

```
SELECT pv.nombre, SUM(tf.total) AS 'total'
FROM ventas v
JOIN puntoVenta pv ON v.idPuntoVenta = pv.id
JOIN totalFactura tf ON v.codeFac = tf.codeFac
WHERE v.idEvento = '2' AND v.status = 'approved'
GROUP BY pv.nombre, v.codeFac;
```

Pero no funciona. La agrupación por `GROUP BY v.codeFac` es obligatoria.

Comment: Puedes Colocar tus tablas? para realizar pruebas exactas

Comment: Si codeFac es obligatoria entonces no obtienes el total por punto de venta, obtienes el total por punto de venta y código de factura. Podrías utilizar la consulta que realizas como subtabla??

Comment: Hola Jose, tu group by no deberia ser asi **GROUP BY pv.nombre, tf.total;**, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez solamente te hace falta un select, prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
SELECT pv.nombre, SUM(tf.total) AS 'total'
FROM ventas v
JOIN puntoVenta pv ON v.idPuntoVenta = pv.id
JOIN totalFactura tf ON v.codeFac = tf.codeFac
WHERE v.idEvento = '2' AND v.status = 'approved'
GROUP BY pv.nombre,tf.total;
```